# ExpandableListView first child

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Is there a way to get the index of the first child of each group regardless of position displayed to the screen? I used 0 as index but when I started to scroll up and down the page it would apply changes to all children, I suspect because child[0] was no longer the first one in the group but the first one on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your adapter to get this index (given that your items have indexes)
`yourExpandableAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getIndex();`

where `getIndex()` is a method in your adapter item object.

Answer (score 0):

The expandable listview cosists of group and children for each group. Override the getChildId of the BaseExpandableListAdapter (or a subclass of it you are using). Call the method getChildID(0,0). list_parents is an arraylist that holding each group. In this example each group element contains all the child inside. If you have different data structures for groups and children follow a similar way.

```
@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    if (groupPosition < 0 || childPosititon < 0)
        return null;
    else
        returnthis.list_children.get(list_parents.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
}
```